# Wordpress Filter dashboard custom post by user with relations

Tags: wordpress, filter, admin, custom-post-type, dashboard

I have custom post type `umowy` which one have relationship with user. Relationship is adding by acf by editing user. What I want? I want to list in dashboard custom post type `umowy` all post which have relations with user logged in. I have code like that. And its showing post only for user login which one is author. Someone have idea for that?

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list');
function filter_posts_list($query)
{
    //$pagenow holds the name of the current page being viewed
     global $pagenow, $typenow;  

    //$current_user uses the get_currentuserinfo() method to get the currently logged in user's data
     global $current_user;
     get_currentuserinfo();

        //Shouldn't happen for the admin, but for any role with the edit_posts capability and only on the posts list page, that is edit.php
        if(!current_user_can('administrator') && current_user_can('edit_posts') && ('edit.php' == $pagenow) &&  $typenow == 'umowy')
     { 
        //global $query's set() method for setting the author as the current user's id
        $query->set('author', $current_user->ID);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer:

```
if(!current_user_can('administrator') && !current_user_can('obsluga') && ('edit.php' == $pagenow) &&  $typenow == 'umowy'){

    $key = 'użytkownik_sklep';
    $single = true;
    $shopIds = get_user_meta($current_user->data->ID, $key, $single); 

    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'umowa_do_sklepu',
            'value' => $shopIds[0],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'umowa_do_sklepu' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

}
```